# java - find sequence of integers whose sum is that of a given number

Tags: java, algorithm

For n < 10. taking 4 for test. I need to print sequences of integers such that the sum of them is n.

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        printAll(4);
    }

    public static void printAll(int k) {
        int count = 0;
        int a[] = new int[k];
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            a[i] = 1;
        }
        int currentSum = 0;
        a[1] = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            a[1]++;
            for (int j = 0; j < k - i; j++) {
                currentSum += a[i];
                count++;
                if (currentSum == k) {
                    for (int m = 0; m < count; m++) {
                        System.out.print(a[m] + " ");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
            count = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

for n = 4:

Desired output:

```
    1 1 1 1
    1 2 1 
    1 3
```

Output I get:

```
    1 1 1 1
```

This is actually the first step of code. Later i need to print

```
    2 1 1
    2 2
```

So basically my target is to get sum equal to 4(in this case) at each step of iteration

Comment: for your desired output, does it need to be in a specific order? Like in first example: would `2 1 1` be acceptable instead of `1 2 1` ?

Comment: Yes, it should be in the same order as given in the question.

Comment: Define "sequence of integers". Is it a sub-sequence of some given sequence? Is it any set of integers less then the given number?

Comment: The mathematical phrase for one of these sequences is a "partition".  So you're wanting to list **all** of the partitions of `n`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pattern which I would use to solve this problem.

Notice this:

```
example: 4 //i starts at 0 and increments 1
1 1 1 1 = 1 1+i 1 1  //4-i numbers
1 2 1   = 1 1+i 1    //4-i numbers
1 3     = 1 1+i      //4-i numbers

example: 8
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 = 1 1+i 1 1 1 1 1 1 //8-i numbers
1 2 1 1 1 1 1   = 1 1+i 1 1 1 1 1   //8-i numbers
1 3 1 1 1 1     = 1 1+i 1 1 1 1     //8-i numbers
1 4 1 1 1       //and so on...
1 5 1 1
1 6 1
1 7

//Now we introduce a new level, with 'j' (j was 0 in previous example, now it is 1)
//We add i to j in the second position in the array
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 = 1+j j+i 1 1 1 1 //8-j-i numbers
2 2 1 1 1 1   = 1+j j+i 1 1 1   //8-j-i numbers
2 3 1 1 1     = 1+j j+i 1 1     //8-j-i numbers
2 4 1 1       = 1+j j+i 1       //8-j-i numbers
2 5 1
2 6
```

Putting this pattern together, we only use two different variables i and j, so we probably only need two for loops. (like you have.)

```
int exampleNumber = 8;
for (int j = 0; j < exampleNumber; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < exampleNumber; i++)
    {

    }
}
```

Next, we know we start with an array of 8-j length, and then shrink it when i increments as well.

```
int exampleNumber = 8;
for (int j = 0; j < exampleNumber; j++)
{
    int jLength = exampleNumber - j; //NewLine
    for (int i = 0; i < exampleNumber; i++)
    {
        int iArray = new int[jLength - i]; //NewLine
    }
}
```

Now we just have to set the two important numbers. The one at the start and the one next to it.

```
int exampleNumber = 8;
for (int j = 0; j < exampleNumber; j++)
{
    int jLength = exampleNumber - j;
    for (int i = 0; i < exampleNumber; i++)
    {
        int iArray = new int[jLength - i];
        iArray[0] = 1 + j; //NewLine
        iArray[1] = j + i; //NewLine
    }
}
```

Finally, we just need to print what we have. We substitue 1's where the array is null.

```
int exampleNumber = 8;
for (int j = 0; j < exampleNumber; j++)
{
    int jLength = exampleNumber - j;
    for (int i = 0; i < exampleNumber; i++)
    {
        int iArray = new int[jLength - i];
        iArray[0] = 1 + j;
        iArray[1] = j + i;
        //printIntArray(iArray);
    }
}

public void printIntArray(int[] printArray)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < printArray.length(); i++)
    {
        int numberToPrint = printArray[i];
        if (numberToPrint == null || numberToPrint == 0)
            numberToPrint = 1;
        System.out.print(numberToPrint + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: no the pattern will be like this
  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  1 2 1 1 1 1 1
  1 3 1 1 1 1
  1 4 1 1 1 
  1 5 1 1
  1 6 1
  1 7

  this is basically the first iteration of what i'm trying to process

  when the loop increments the next pattern will be
 2 1 1 1 1 1 1
  2 2 1 1 1 1
  2 3 1 1 1
  2 4 1 1 
  2 5 1
  2 6

  and so on... till we get 8 as the only set

Comment: may want to edit your initial post with that pattern as well.

Comment: 1 4 1 1 1 
  1 5 1 1
  1 6 1
  1 7

  this is basically the first iteration of what i'm trying to process

  when the loop increments the next pattern will be
 2 1 1 1 1 1 1
  2 2 1 1 1 1
  2 3 1 1 1
  2 4 1 1 
  2 5 1
  2 6

  and so on... till we get 8 as the only set

Comment: sequence of integer refers to the subset at each iteration in the respective loop.

Answer (score 0):

How about this less complicated solution:

```
public static void allSequencesSumToN(int n) {
    generate(n,"", n);
}

public static void generate(int no, String str, int orig) {
    if(no == 0) {
        System.out.println(str);
        return;
    }
    if(no < 0) {
        return;
    }
    for(int i = 1; i < orig ; i++) {
        waysUtil(no - i, str + i, orig);
    }

}
```

It might be slightly different than what you need, but you can adjust the result. E.g. input 4, this will generate following output:

1111
112
121
13
211
22
31

All possible sequences, but with easy postprocessing you can achieve exactly what you need.